# Connect Logic Apps to MQ in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

I am struggling connecting a Logic App to MQ in the IBM Cloud.

I created a Queue Manager in MQ and want to send some test message to any of the default queues.

[image: MQ]

The Logic App connector wants the Queue Manager, Channel and Queue.

[image: Logic App]

I created a Channel of Type Receiver, not sure why this is needed, but created it.

When I try to connect I got an error.

[image: Logic App Error]

Tried using the port as well, (tried 30127 and 1414, 30127 the port assigned to the Queue Manager) and received an error, though a different error.

[image: Logic App New Error]

This is my first time working with MQ, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a channel of type RECEIVER, instead you need a channel of type SVRCONN. In your screenshot that asks for a 'Channel Name' with description 'The channel to connect to the queue manager on' it must be a channel of type SVRCONN whose name you supply in that field.

Could you update your question to show how you used the port? If the port number is not 1414, then you will certainly need to supply it as well.

Comment: Added the port information, tried 1414 and the one assigned by IBM Cloud. Probably the Channel that is messing me up. I can't create a channel of type SVRCONN, the only one's available to me are: Sender, Server, Receiver, Requester, Cluster-receiver and Cluster-sender.

Comment: Is there "server connection" as an option?   This would be the longer name for SVRCONN and is different than a "server" channel.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of where the channel types are offered to you?